# C++ undeclared identifier on lines 16, 17, and 18

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to call the Triangle method however I don't seem to be doing it correctly in the main. on line 16 i have 3 errors:

> Triangle: undeclared identifier, syntax error missing ';' before
> identifier 'newTriangle' and newTriangle undeclared identifier

On line 17 it says newTriangle undeclared identifier, and line 18 newTriangle undeclared identifier.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm leaving out.

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

//Base Class (Abstract/Interface)
class Interface{

public:
    virtual int area() = 0;
    virtual int perimeter() = 0;
};

int main() {
    Triangle newTriangle;
     newTriangle.area();
     newTriangle.perimeter();
};

//Triangle
class Triangle : public Interface {
    int s1 = 3;
    int s2 = 5;

public:
    int area() {
        double a = ((s1 * s2) * 1 / 2);
        cout << "The area of the triangle:";
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    int perimeter() {
        double b = (s1 + s2 + s2);
        cout << "The perimeter of the triangle is: ";
        cout << b << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Voting to close as typo, or probably there is a duplicate for this: You must declare classes _before_ using them. Just move the definition of `Triangle` above `main`

Comment: at the point where you want to use "Triangle", the compiler doesn't know anything about it yet ( since the code for it is yet to come, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTcu7MCtuTs ). Move the definition up, or forward-declare it.

Comment: First and foremost mistake is you are using class before you declared it, and second mistake is present in your function ***area()*** and ***perimeter()*** which are non-void type function, but still not returned any useful data, that result in **out of reach warning**.

Comment: I gotcha! That makes sense now! Thank you, I did that and it worked. Im not familiar with c++ very much, im just trying to convert my Java programs into C++ so implementing is new to me on this.

Comment: @WesleyHarrison don't try to convert Java programs into C++. You will end up copying something that is valid Java and valid C++, but has a different meaning in each, and not realise.

Comment: @Caleth its part of what we have to do in Data Structure class.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


//Base Class (Abstract/Interface)

class Interface{

public:

    virtual void area() = 0;

    virtual void perimeter() = 0;

};
class Triangle : public Interface {
private:
int s1,s2;
public:
     void get(int a,int b)
     {
         s1=a;
         s2=b;
     }
    void area() {

        double a = ((s1 * s2) * 1 / 2);

        cout << "The area of the triangle:";

        cout << a << endl;
    }
    void perimeter() {
        double b = (s1 + s2 + s2);
        cout << "The perimeter of the triangle is: ";
        cout << b << endl;
    }
};




int main() {

    Triangle newTriangle;
    newTriangle.get(3,5);
     newTriangle.area();

     newTriangle.perimeter();

}
```